# show result of one table and find in other column

Tags: mysql

let me show table structure first then my question

suppose table A

```
  id | url |
  1  | page
  2  | home
  3  | product
  4  | sell
```

and table b

```
 id |user_id | table a id
  1 | 1      | 1
```

the output which I want like

```
  id | url     |   ispermission
  1  | page    | 1
  2  | home    | 0
  3  | product | 0
  4  | sell    | 0
```

(value 1 )in ispermission mean that it  map with user as you can see in table b other mean it does not have mapping 
below is my query

```
 select p.id,p.url,if(r.user_id=4,1,0) ispermission from  
 `table a` p
 left join `table b` r on p.id=r.url_id  
 group by p.id,p.url order by ispermission DESC
```

this query is working great but in some case it got failed the result let conside that failed case the output which i m getting like (note this result is without groupby)

```
     id | url     |   ispermission
     1  | page    | 0
     1  | page    | 1
     2  | home    | 0
     3  | product | 0
     4  | sell    | 0
```

by using group by i m getting result like

```
     id | url     |   ispermission
     1  | page    | 0
     2  | home    | 0
     3  | product | 0
     4  | sell    | 0
```

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle <> SQL Server. Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using (you have enough reputation to know how tags work). I have removed all of these; please update your post to be appropriate for your environment.

Comment: left join comes to mind.

Comment: Your expected output seems to be missing a `user_id` column.  Do you want the user information to also appear in your output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i update my question with my query

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT 
T1.ID, 
T1.Url, 
COUNT(T2.[table a id]) Impression
FROM TableA T1
LEFT JOIN TableB T2 ON  T1.ID  = T2.[table a id]
GROUP BY T1.ID,T1.Url
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LEFT JOIN` with `CASE` expression:

```
select a.id, a.url,
       case when b.tableAid is not null then 1 else 0 end as ispermission
from TableA a
left join TableB b on b.tableAid = a.id
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=122e5adf78b4a96d5d80c1e964d54e14)

Comment: this same query i m using but it has problem i described in my question

Comment: @bipin No need of `GROUP BY` in your query

Comment: if i don't use group by it give the result of repeating column